# How to remove the white bar at top of screen in Vim?

Tags: vim, vi

To recreate, do `:set background=dark`, and you’ll see it on top of the screen. I’m using the railscasts theme, but I don’t think it has anything to do with that.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Setting `background=dark` is not enough to show the tabline, you should start recreation with `vim -u NONE`.

By default tabline does not appear unless there is more then one tab. This behavior is controlled by `showtabline` option which defaults to `1`. `0` switches off tabline even if there is more then one tab, `2` makes tabline to be shown even if there is only one tab. Try `verbose set showtabline?` to find out what script replaced `showtabline=1` with `showtabline=2`.

Comment: I didn't notice this earlier, it still appears when there is more than one tab. It is set to 0 properly.

Answer (score 1):

It's the tabline which is not dealt with by the railscasts colorscheme. If you want the tabline but don't want it to be white you'll need to edit your colorscheme to your liking.

Start by adding the following:

```
hi TabLine      guifg=<hexadecimal color> guibg=<hexadecimal color>
hi TabLineFill  guifg=<hexadecimal color> guibg=<hexadecimal color> gui=reverse
hi TabLineSel   guifg=<hexadecimal color> guibg=<hexadecimal color> gui=bold
hi Title        guifg=<hexadecimal color> guibg=<hexadecimal color> gui=bold
```

These are specific to GVim/MacVim, to make it work in the terminal, you'll need to add

```
ctermfg=<color number> ctermbg=<color number> cterm=<value>
```

to each line.

See `:help colorscheme`.